# tar: samtools-1.9.tar: cannot open: no such file or directory

Tags: unix, bash-scripting, tar, ubuntu-18.04, linux-terminal

I am trying to run the command to install samtools on ubuntu but I am facing a problem here whenever I try to use tar.

Input : `/c/Users/Hamza Bilal$ tar -xvf samtools-1.9.tar.bz2`

The Output I get every time is:

```
tar: samtools-1.9.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Kindly help me with this error.

Comment: try adding -j i.e. tar -xjvf samtools-1.9.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deal with compressed `tar` archive. So first you should decompress and then untar. As mentioned in comment you can use command like:

```
 tar -xjvf samtools-1.9.tar.bz
```

Take attention to `j` key which mean extract `bzip` archive before untar